# How to compare only month and year? [VB]

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Its quite simple, i just want to compare two dates using month and year, if the input date (mont and year only) are above or below that current date (month and year).

The problem is , when i compare two strings

```
Dim dDate as DateTime

If Not (DateTime.TryParse(txtBox.Text, dDate)) Then
 MessageBox.Show("check date.")
Else
 txtBox.Text = dDate.ToString("MM/yyyy")
end If

IF dDate.ToString("MM/yyyy") < DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/yyyy")
 MessageBox.Show("Below") ' Problem: 03/2024 saying is below than 08/2019
Else
 MessageBox.Show("Above")
End If
```

Any help?

UPDATE

I CHANGED THE CASE TO

```
If (dDate.Month AndAlso dDate.Year) < (DateTime.Now.Month AndAlso DateTime.Now.Year) Then
 'input: 07/2019 
 'date expired
Else
'the problem is here
'saying 07/2019 is not < than 08/2019
End If
```

Comment: String comparisons never consider the numeric value, just the lexical value.  You need to either use a different format or shadow the value(s) with proper DateTime values and display just a portion

Comment: @preciousbetine Always a good idea to have Option Strict on but what makes you think the OP doesn't have it on? I see no errors in the code that Option Strict would detect.

Comment: thank you guys, my problem is with dates are not validating if the month and year are under the current time. The code is running farewell

Comment: @Mary Since your comment, the OP has revealed it's set to off: `dDate.Month AndAlso dDate.Year` etc.

Comment: `If (dDate.Month AndAlso dDate.Year) < (DateTime.Now.Month AndAlso DateTime.Now.Year) Then` is not going to compare date values. It will not tell you if one date is less or greater than another.

Comment: thx MArk and Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, but the final solutions is made with

```
If (dDate.Year < DateTime.Now.Year Or (dDate.Year = DateTime.Now.Year And dDate.Month < DateTime.Now.Month)) Then
  'something                
 Else
  'something
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using strings.

```
    Dim dDate As DateTime
    If Not (DateTime.TryParse(txtBox.Text, dDate)) Then
        'bad date
        MessageBox.Show("check date.")
    Else
        Select Case dDate.Year
            Case Is < DateTime.Now.Year
                MessageBox.Show("Below")
            Case Is > DateTime.Now.Year
                MessageBox.Show("Above")

            Case Else 'years are equal,check month
                Select Case dDate.Month
                    Case Is < DateTime.Now.Month
                        MessageBox.Show("Below")
                    Case Is > DateTime.Now.Month
                        MessageBox.Show("Above")
                    Case Else 'equal months
                        MessageBox.Show("SAME") '????
                End Select
        End Select
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Using date values is probably best, but if string comparisons must be made.

```
Dim dDate as DateTime

If Not (DateTime.TryParse(txtBox.Text, dDate)) Then
  MessageBox.Show("check date.")
Else
  txtBox.Text = dDate.ToString("yyyyMM")
End If

If dDate.ToString("yyyyMM") < DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") Then
  MessageBox.Show("Below") 
ElseIf dDate.ToString("yyyyMM") > DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") Then
  MessageBox.Show("Above")
Else
  MessageBox.Show("Same")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the year and month to `Integer` values, which are easy to compare less-than or greater-than. For example, if you had two DateTimePicker controls on a form, named `dtpDate1` and `dptDate2`, and a button `btnTest`:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click

    Dim date1 As Integer = (dtpDate1.Value.Year * 100) + dtpDate1.Value.Month
    Dim date2 As Integer = (dtpDate2.Value.Year * 100) + dtpDate2.Value.Month

    MsgBox("Date1 = " & date1.ToString & vbCrLf & "Date2 = " & date2.ToString)

    If date1 = date2 Then MsgBox("Equal!")
    If date1 < date2 Then MsgBox("date1 is less than date2")
    If date1 > date2 Then MsgBox("date1 is greater than date2")

End Sub
```

The dates are converted to integers in a YYYYMM format. This is a data warehouse technique to convert dates to integers for better query performance when date is used often in a WHERE clause.